# SQL Conditional AND Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add a clause that does the following:

```
DECLARE @RequiresApproval BIT
SET @RequiresApproval = 0
SELECT * FROM [user] u
WHERE school_id = 1
```

Here's my logic I want

- when @RequiresApproval = 1, then add the clause: AND approved = 1
- when @RequiresApproval = 0, then leave out the clause: AND approved = 1

My goal is to have SQL will end up like either one of the following, depending on the value of @RequiresApproval.  Is this possible to do?

```
-- when @RequiresApproval = 1, use this
SELECT * FROM [user] u
WHERE school_id = 1


-- when @RequiresApproval = 0, use this
SELECT * FROM [user] u
WHERE school_id = 1
AND approved = 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok.  This should implement your logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM [user] u
WHERE school_id = 1 AND
      (@RequiresApproval = 0 or approved = 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this query - you just need to use `OR` between your two conditions.

```
SELECT * FROM [user] u
WHERE school_id = 1
AND (approved = 1 OR @RequiresApproval = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also work..

```
SELECT  * FROM  [user] u
WHERE   [school_id] = 1 AND [approved] = 1 
AND     @RequiresApproval = 1
UNION 
SELECT  * FROM  [user] u 
WHERE   [school_id] = 1 AND @RequiresApproval = 0
```